# Не сработали обработчики

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

По клику на кнопки не происходят события

```
<div id="buttonWrapper">
    <input type="button" id="button1" />
    <input type="button" id="button2" />
 </div>
        <script>

  var Job = Backbone.View.extend({
     //el: '#buttonWrapper',
     events: {
      'click #button1': 'eventHandler1', 
      'click #button2': 'eventHandler2',   
   },
   eventHandler1:function(){
       console.log('eventHandler1')
   },

       eventHandler2:function(){
       console.log('eventHandler2')
   }

  })
   var obj= new Job;
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PWxth/

1. У вас закоментарино свойство `el`
2. Код инициализируется  перед HTML, а нужно после, либо на DOMContentReady

Comment: DOM-ready помог.Благодарен